# Accumulator function to reduce stream of HibernateSearch SearchPredicates

Tags: java, java-stream, hibernate-search

The following example (Example 183) taken from https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-predicate explains how to apply multiple filters to a HibernateSearch query:

```
List<Book> hits = searchSession.search( Book.class )
        .where( f -> f.bool() 
                .should( f.bool() 
                        .filter( f.match().field( "genre" )
                                .matching( Genre.SCIENCE_FICTION ) ) 
                        .must( f.match().fields( "description" )
                                .matching( "crime" ) ) 
                )
                .should( f.bool() 
                        .filter( f.match().field( "genre" )
                                .matching( Genre.CRIME_FICTION ) ) 
                        .must( f.match().fields( "description" )
                                .matching( "robot" ) ) 
                )
        )
        .fetchHits( 20 );
```

However, if I understand the documentation correctly, I always have to apply the filters individually (here: Genre = "Science Fiction" or Genre = Crime Fiction").

Instead, I need to apply an arbitrary list of filters to a HibernateSearch search query, for example provided as a `Map<String, String>`, where each entrys key represents a filter fields name and the entrys value is the filter fields value.

I have tried to first create a list of search predicates in the following way:

```
List<SearchPredicate> searchPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> filterEntry : filterMap.entrySet()) {
    searchPredicates.add(scope.predicate().match().field(filterEntry.getKey())
            .matching(filterEntry.getValue()).toPredicate());
}
```

And then apply this list of predicates in the `filter` clause of the query by creating a stream and than reduce the stream as explained in https://www.baeldung.com/java-predicate-chain.

I am unable however to identify appropriate 'identity' SearchPredicate and 'accumulator' function parameters for the "reduce" function of the stream (I use `must()` instead of `should()` because I want *all* my filters to apply instead of just one, so a logical conjunction instead of a disjunction as in the example above):

```
List<MyClass> hits = searchSession.search(MyClass.class)
  .where( f -> f.bool()
    .must( f.bool()
      .filter(searchPredicates.stream()
        .reduce(SearchPredicateFactory::matchAll, (partialResult, nextFilter) -> f.bool().must(nextFilter))))
        .fetchHits(10));
```

Neither of those two parameters for the "reduce" function is good, though:

- I chose `SearchPredicateFactory::matchAll` because I wanted to get *all* documents if no filters where applied, but here I get the error `SearchPredicate is not a functional interface`.
- `(partialResult, nextFilter) -> f.bool().must(nextFilter))` was supposed to add the next `SearchPredicate` filter to the existing filter chain, but here I get the error message `Bad return type in lambda expression: capture of ? cannot be converted to SearchPredicate`.

Is there even an appropriate accumulator function for HibernateSearch SearchPredicates (and if yes: what would be the corresponding 'identity' for it?) or would I need to write one myself?

(Sorry if this is a naive question, I read the documentation for HibernateSearch and Java predicates, but I guess I am still a relative beginner concerning these topics and couldn't find the same issue I am trying to solve - apply list of search predicates to HibernateSearch query - covered elsewhere)

**Edit**: I updated my attempt after reading https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-reduce which gave me at least a little more insight of how "reduce" and it's parameters are supposed to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say `reduce` is not the right tool for this job.

The Hibernate Search DSL provides builder-like instances (like `b` below) that can aggregate multiple predicates: just use them. You don't even need streams here.

Wouldn't it be enough to use `f.bool(b -> { ... })`, where `b` acts like an accumulator, like this?

```java
Map<String, String> searchParameters = getSearchParameters(); 
List<MyClass> hits = searchSession.search( MyClass.class )
        .where( f -> f.bool( b -> { 
            b.must( f.matchAll() ); // By default, return all documents
            // ... unless field/value pairs are provided,
            // in which case return documents that match every field/value pair.
            for ( Map.Entry<String, String> filterEntry : filterMap.entrySet() ) {
                b.must( f.match().field( filterEntry.getKey() )
                        .matching( filterEntry.getValue() ) );
            }
        } ) )
        .fetchHits( 10 );
```

It's pretty much what is suggested in [this section of the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-boolean-lambda).

If you *really* need to use streams for some reason, I suppose something like this could work:

```java
List<SearchPredicate> searchPredicates = getSearchPredicates();
List<MyClass> hits = searchSession.search( MyClass.class )
        .where( f -> f.bool( b -> { 
            b.must( f.matchAll() ); // By default, return all documents
            // ... unless predicates are provided,
            // in which case return documents that match every predicate.
            searchPredicates.stream().forEach( b::must );
        } ) )
        .fetchHits( 10 );
```

And if you're a functional programming extremist, using `collect` instead of `reduce` could work, but quite frankly it's very ugly code, much worse than the two suggestions above:

```java
List<SearchPredicate> searchPredicates = getSearchPredicates();
List<MyClass> hits = searchSession.search( MyClass.class )
        .where( f -> f.bool()
                .must( f.matchAll() ) // By default, return all documents
                // PLEASE DO YOUR COWORKERS A FAVOR: DON'T DO THIS
                .must(searchPredicates.stream().collect(
                        () -> f.bool(),
                        BooleanPredicateClausesStep::must,
                        (left, right) -> f.bool().must( left ).must( right ) ) )
        )
        .fetchHits( 10 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That (the first - and presumably best - option you provided) is exactly what I needed! I don't need to use streams, but just thought there was no other option. I guess I overlooked https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-boolean-lambda in the very comprehensive HibernateSearch documentation!

Comment: Thank you also for this comment of yours: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hs-6-custom-bridges/4577/4 It helped me finish the typed filter map I needed!